# How to register gimbal beacon on Apple Developer Console

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, gimbal

I am working on Gimbal Beacons. I have registered my gimbal beacon on [Google Beacon DashBoard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/). Now I can receive notification on any android device using my gimbal beacon. Now I want to do the same thing for iPhones. So that when an iPhone user opens bluetooth in beacon's range then a notification is received on iPhone. Please help me..!

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not have an equivalent of Google's Nearby functionality that allows Android devices with Google Play Services to receive notifications when a beacon is in vicinity without a third party app installed.

On iOS devices, a third part app is generally required to send notifications for nearby beacons.  Only one built-in app and one fairly common add-on app allow on iOS respond to third party beacons:

- Passbook: if a user has installed a pass associated with a beacon, a notification will be displayed when it is nearby.
- Google Chrome: responds to Eddystone-URL beacons if the Chrome Today widget gas been enabled.  (Very few iOS users have Chrome and enable this.)

Other than the above, you need a third party app to make iOS respond to beacons.